# Enum.map_every even number

Tags: numbers, elixir, enumerable

`Enum.map` can be used to change the values of the odd elements of a list:

```erlang
iex(13)> [1,2,3,4,5,6] |> Enum.map_every(2, &(&1 + 100))
[101, 2, 103, 4, 105, 6]
```

However it appears that there needs to be an offset of `1` to do the same for the even elements of the list.

Is there a function that can directly `map_every` even number?

Comment: My guess would be that there is not. Most likely you will need to implement it in a bit more complicated way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While shifting the original list works, I don’t really think that’s the proper way to go. Whether one needs the *even* elements to be updated, this might be done explicitly:

```
require Integer

[1,2,3,4,5,6]
|> Enum.map_every(1, &(if Integer.is_even(&1), do: &1 + 100, else: &1))
#⇒ [1, 102, 3, 104, 5, 106]
```

The same applies to any cumbersome condition: one just calls `Enum.map_every/3` with `nth` argument set to `1` and performs an additional check in the reducer, returning either modified value, or the original one.

---

The the condition should be applied to *an index*, wrap the input using [`Enum.with_index/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#with_index/1)

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
|> Enum.with_index
|> Enum.map_every(1, fn {e, idx} ->
     if Integer.is_even(idx), do: e + 100, else: e
   end)
```

Comment: While this works for every even element, I understood the question as "every even (array index) number". When just the element is important, you can also directly switch to `Enum.map/2` instead of `Enum.map_every/3`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function that does this.

However, it can be achieved with 2 lines by shifting the array and using `Enum.map_every/3`

```
iex(1)> [head | tail] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
iex(2)> [head | Enum.map_every(2, tail, &(&1 + 100))]
[1, 102, 3, 104, 5, 106]
```

You could also build a function like below. It will start mapping at the provided `nth`, instead of the first element:

```
def map_every_alt(enumerable, nth, fun) when nth > 0 do
  Enum.take(enumerable, nth - 1) ++
    Enum.map_every(Enum.drop(enumerable, nth - 1), nth, fun)
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I think there should also be an offset additional argument to `Enum.map_every`.